# postgresql trigger to select values when update

Tags: postgresql-9.3

Here is my Table called `table_abc`:

[image: table_abc screenshot]

I need to write a Trigger such that when this table is updated, a Select query gets fired to retrieve the updated records.

In `postgresql`, triggers must go through a stored procedure.

So, I have used a `table` as return type for my procedure but I am getting error as `table` return type is not allowed. Could anyone help me writing this trigger/procedure?

```
//procedure:
CREATE FUNCTION abc() RETURNS trigger AS $abc$
    BEGIN
        //here i want write a QUERY to rerieve updated row details when updating table_abc
    END;
$abc$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

//trigger
CREATE TRIGGER abc BEFORE UPDATE ON table_abc
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE abc();

//update query:
UPDATE table_abc SET x=7,y=8 WHERE id=2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a trigger for that, simply use:

```
UPDATE table_abc 
   SET x=7,
       y=8 
WHERE id=2
RETURNING *;
```

Comment: This works properly.thanks a lot ...this answer saved me. thank you for kindness !!